# Is there equivalent comparison of JS's === operator in Visual Basic?

Tags: vba

Is there a equivalent of the === operator (of JavaScript) in Visual Basic? I'm trying to learn Visual Basic and seen that assignment can only be statement, if used in expressions it turns the equivalent of == operator in JavaScript (comparison operator).

However, the === operator of JavaScript does a observable comparison between values, if the type of both values aren't equal, it returns `false`. For example:

```js
2 === "2" // false
2 == "2" // true ("2" == "2")
```

I need to do a comparison similiar of === without using Visual Basic's = operator, is it possible and how?

Comment: I've not discovered this comparison oeprator before but I am a relative n00b. There's `TypeName(x)` which returns the variable type of x, and `TypeName(x) = TypeName(y)` will return True if they're the same type... that's using the = operator though... why can't you use the = operator?

Comment: @jamheadart I think the = operator will decrease the performance of the VBa execution. What I thought is that I'd need a comparison between the type of each value as in your comment it's, but I'm not sure if there's a native function better to do that (without losing performance).

Comment: Ah I see. Judging by the answers below and what I could see on the official documentation, there's no === equivalent in VBA :/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**tl;dr** No, VBA doesn't have a strict equity operator.

As you noted, VBA uses `=` for both the equity and assignment operator.  Which operator it functions as is entirely dependant on the expression.  Note that unlike some languages, in VBA an assignment operation does not have a return value (i.e. in a C statement like `a = b = c`.  This means the parser can determine if the operation is assignment or equity based entirely dependant on the grammar.

Turning to Java and JavaScript specifically, the main difference is that not everything is an object in VBA, and *all* of the comparisons are made on value types as opposed to reference types.  If you want to compare object references, you would use the object comparison operator `Is`:

```
Dim foo As Object, bar As Object
'Initialize, yada, yada
If foo Is bar Then  'Tests reference equity
```

If you use the equity operator `=`, VBA will actually test the equity of the *default member of the object* or throw an exception if it doesn't have one. For example, assume a `Foo` object has a default property `Value`:

```
Dim x As Foo, y As Foo
'Initialize, yada, yada
If x = y Then               'This statement is equivalent to:
If x.Value = y.Value Then
```

As far as *strict equity* is concerned, VBA will attempt to cast variables on either side of the equity operator `=` to equivalent types. For this reason, it's much better practice to use strongly typed variables instead of `Variant`, and explicitly call the default member of objects instead of implicitly using the default member.

For objects you can test the type with the `TypeOf` operator:

```
Dim x As Foo, y As Foo
If TypeOf x Is Foo And TypeOf y Is Foo Then
```

Primitive types don't have an equivalent to `TypeOf`:

```
Dim foo As String
If TypeOf foo Is String Then     'Compile error
```

You can use the `TypeName()` function as a proxy, but be aware that it will return the *subtype* of a `Variant`.  AFAIK there is no direct test to determine if a variable is a `Variant`:

```
Dim foo As String, bar As Variant
foo = "2"
bar = 2
Debug.Print TypeName(foo)   'String
Debug.Print TypeName(bar)   'Integer
bar = "2"
Debug.Print TypeName(bar)   'String
```

Comment: AFAIK there is no direct test to determine if a variable is a Variant << might want to change this. Use `LenB(VarPtr(foo))=16`. Though might want to test how pointers of structs and arrays act...

Comment: @Sancarn `LenB(VarPtr(foo))` is a compile error. I see where you're going with that (`sizeof(VARIANT)`), but that's still not a definitive test. Consider the case of a `Type` with 4 members of type `Long`.  That's also 16 bytes.  That's also on the borderline of what I would consider "direct" - the "non-direct" test for a `Variant` is fairly trivial.

Comment: "LenB(VarPtr(foo)) is a compile error"... Lol, I don't know why I thought that would work... xD And yeah I had mentioned that `struct`s might have similar behaviour. I didn't know for sure though. After testing however, they definitely do :) So as you said, not a definitive test.

Answer (score 0):

There is no strict comparison operator in VBA. As a workaround, you would have to compare the values using `=` and compare the types as well, like this:

```
"1" = 1 And TypeName("1") = TypeName(1) // false
```